# R: UTF-8 character bytes as Latin-1 characters bytes

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, character, iso-8859-1

I get UTF-8 character bytes as Latin-1 character bytes. Examples contain

```
Latin 1 character bytes        ----- UTF-8 bytes
Ã¤Ã¤nnÃ¶k                      ----- äännök
Ã<U+0084>Ã<U+0084>NÃ<U+0096>S  ----- äänös
```

and my session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**So what kind of settings do I need in R to handle umlauts correctly (not to return UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 character bytes)?**

*Related?*

> 1. [Turn Unicode into Umlaut in R on Mac (Facebook Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34693989/164148)
> 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945233/164148
> 3. Apparently by [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding), I need to
>
> > *If you call **Sys.setlocale** with **"LC_CTYPE" or "LC_ALL"** to change the system locale while RStudio is running, you may run into some minor issues as RStudio assumes the system encoding doesn't change. If you are on Windows, we recommend you only call **Sys.setlocale in .Rprofile**. If you are on Mac or Linux and want to change the system locale, please visit the support forum and let us know your scenario.*
>
> 4. Does there exist some simple tool to convert the Latin-1 character bytes to UTF-8 character bytes?

*P.s. I have tested this now in R on Linux and R on OSX, I get the same problem of interpreting the UTF-8 character bytes as Latin-1 character bytes.*

Comment: I cannot even run your example code on my machine. I get an `Error: unexpected input in "Ã¤"`. Please share your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: This suggests that your R source file is using a wonky encoding. Be sure to save it as UTF-8 (everything else is useless). If that doesn’t help, post a minimal example of some code that displays this issue.

Comment: @Roland shared.